# How to make WPF MVVM application connect to multiple WCF Services?

Tags: wpf, wcf, mvvm, loginview

I have 4 WCF services that I have developed.

Each service is responsible for something else.

Each service has a *UserNamePasswordValidator*, so clients need to supply credentials when connecting.

I would now like to develop my WPF client application, in an MVVM architecture.

I would like for the WPF application to load with a ***'Login'*** screen,

where the user will input a username and password,

and then this will be passed on to the 4 clients for the 4 WCF services (all use the same username and password).

What is the best approach to doing this ?

Where are the clients located ? in the 'Model' part ? which view's model ?

The WCF Service needs to be consumed by multiple views, so I don't think I can put any of the WCF service clients in a *specific* Model class...

Answer (score 1):

To do this, we have created a ServiceFactory class that connects to a service given its endpoint and an appropriate `IClientChannel`-derived interface. This assumes that you are using the WCF services directly, e.g. not via the VS-generated proxies, since you need to set the username and password values on each client channel creation.

The client channel interfaces are in an external "service library" along with the service factory, so they can be shared with the WCF service implementations and the clients. We store the credentials in a static state dictionary (though you also put it, for example, into the main resource dictionary) with the password being saved in a `SecuredString` for a tiny bit of extra security.

I've described the basic process for creating such a service factory on by blog:

http://blog.kutulu.org/2012/03/proxy-free-wcf-ditching-proxy.html

In our case, we perform a setup routine in `App.xaml.cs` that prompts for credentials and makes an attempt to call one of our services, looping until we get a successful login. That code is much more complex, but it's basically:

```
while (true)
{
  var factory = new ChannelFactory<ITestChannel>(new WSHttpBinding("SecuredBinding"));
  ITestChannel client = null;
  try
  {
    factory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = logOnModel.UserName;
    factory.Credentials.UserName.Password = logOnModel.Password;

    var address = Settings.Default.TestServiceUrlBase));
    client = factory.CreateChannel(address);

    break;
  }
  // Catch various exceptions here.
}
```

The trick here is that, if your login or password is wrong and your `UsernamePasswordValidator` fails your login, you'll get a `MessageSecurityException` which will fault your channel, so you'll need to close it and open a new one. But you cannot change the credentials on a `ChannelFactory` once you've opened the first channel, so you need to dispose and re-create a new factory and new client channel every time.

We also check for `CommunicationException` and `ArgumentException` here in case the URL is wrong.

Once that's done, you can use similar code in your service factory class to construct a client, given its channel interface, and set up the credentials for each call. (We actually cache the service factories for each distinct interface because we create and destroy channel frequently, but that's up to you.)

Comment: In our case - the clients were created using Visual Studio's 'Add Service Reference'. The credentials are simply passed on to the generated client before calling the 'Open()' method. So - I am not sure your approach is suitable in my case ...

Comment: You can still make the same idea work -- a factory class that creates your channels -- its just not going to be as elegant. The VS service reference does create an `IClientChannel` interface for its underlying client interface, which may help out. Or you can simply make a method for each service, if that's a small enough number.

Comment: I have 4 services. Is that small enough ? I am just having trouble understanding how it all connects. So I have a DLL for the 'Service Clients', with the factory in it, but who initiates this ? the 'LoginModel' ? where are the service's instances stored ?

Comment: In our case we make the initial call to the services in the app setup code, in App.xaml.cs, but you could definitely put that into your LoginModel code. (Our LoginModel merely acquires credentials from the user and stores them). For the rest of it, its explained better in the blog post (with pictures) but if you prefer to use the VS auto-generated clients you still can make a factory class for that, you just can't make a single method to open multiple types of proxies.

Comment: and where are the client stored once they manage to connect to the services ? From what I understand - once the 'LoginView' is disposed of, and the 'MainWindow' is shown - so does the 'LoginModel' get disposed, so - where exactly do we keep the 'live' client connections, so that all the views may now use them ?

Comment: you don't keep connections live, you create and dispose of them as needed. You should never keep WCF connections around longer than necessary, because they will time out and fault if they are idle too long. The ServiceFactory class creates new connections on demand.

Comment: And how do the models have access to this 'ServiceFactory' ? By the way, I DO in fact have one specific service that the clients NEED TO BE always connected to, because it is a callback service, that sends the clients notifications of different stuff...

Comment: the service factory is static; everything has access to it. I'm getting the impression that I'm missing something in your question because I can't figure out any better way to explain it than the sample code on the blog...

Comment: When you say 'Service Factory' - is that what is referred to by others as the 'Service Locator' ? because I have read a lot of people argue that 'Service Locator' is an anti-pattern ( [here](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx) )